# Promises with res.send

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise

I have the following problem when returning responses after a promise:

```
let emailSent = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    array.forEach(async (item, i, array) => {
       //asynchronous code for send emails
       if (index === array.length -1) resolve();
    }
})

emailSent.then(() => {
   res.status(201).send({
       message: 'Email sent.',
       status: 201,
   })
}
```

In the browser, the responses never returns.
What the best way to return res.send after a promise?

Comment: Do you ever call `resolve`? Also note that `forEach` doesn't handle promises at all.

Comment: yes, sorry, I forgot to put the resolve in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact code you are using since it looks like you've trimmed a lot, I'd suspect that you have multiple async function calls that you are trying to do in parallel.

For something like that, you should map each async call into a list of promises, and then wait for them all to resolve in one promise with `Promise.all()`, something like this:

```js
let emailSent = Promise.all(
    array.map(async (item, i, array) => {
       //asynchronous code for send emails
    })
});
```